# Calculations on Jquery created items don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this bit of code - works perfectly

```
$('.canti,.precio').change(function() {
 var total = 0;
 var $item = $(this).parent();
 var canti = $item.find(".canti").val();
 var precio = $item.find(".precio").val();  
 total = parseFloat(canti * precio); 
 $item.find(".subto").attr("value", total); 
});
```

it makes calculations based on a field set

```
<fieldset class="item">
<input name="item[]" type"text" value="" />
<input class="canti" name="cantidad[]" type"text" value="" />
<input class="precio" name="preciounitario[]" type"text" value="" />
<input class="subto" name="importe[]" type"text"value="" readonly="readonly"/>
</fieldset>
```

I had multiple actual fieldsets and it worked perfectly. However rather than initially having X fieldsets I wanted the user to be able to add as they required, so wrote this:

```
var newFieldset='<fieldset class="item"><input name="item[]" type"text" value="" /><input class="canti" name="cantidad[]" type"text"  value="" /><input class="precio" name="preciounitario[]" type"text"  value="" /><input class="subto" name="importe[]" type"text"value="" readonly="readonly"/></fieldset>'
$(".add").click(function(){
    $(".add").before(newFieldset);
});
```

Again - works perfectly and adds in a new fieldset BUT the calculations on the .canti and .precio items in the new "virtual" fieldsets don't do anything.

Any ideas? Is what I'm hoping to do even possible?

There's a more complete version at http://www.cristalyaluminiodiestro.com/estimate-create-testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to **delegate the Event**

You can use the jQuery `.on()` method

```
$('body').on('change','.canti,.precio' ,function() {
```

That is because the way you are adding the events will not work for dynamically created elements

'body' can be replaced with the closest static parent container..

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible, you just need to attach the event handler to an element that is a ancestor of all, this is possible using [the `on` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('body').on('change', '.canti,.precio', function() { ... });
```

This is the case because the change handler is only attached to the elements that pass the `'.canti,.precio'` filter on DOM ready - the elements that you add dynamically will obviously not be present and so will not have the handler attached.

In my example above I have used the body element as the common ancestor of all elements, if you're able to do so it is preferable to use a closer common ancestor for performance resons.